# Dealing with a csv file in a strange format

Tags: php, mysql, csv, phpmyadmin

I am using "LOAD DATA" functionality with phpmyadmin to update (or renew) some data in my database with the upload of an csv file. The csv file has 50 cols and 200k lines. This works pretty well and is very fast with this format:

```
100;101;102;103;104;....
Alfred;Mueller;Exampplestreet 1;12121;Chicago;....
John;Wiliams;Exampplestreet 2;12345;Dallas;....
Mandy;Peterson;Exampplestreet 3;44554;LA;....
...
```

Now I ve the chance to fully automize this process by receiving a csv data file of a data provider. But the data provider delivered an csv file like this:

```
100#Alfred;101#Mueller;102#Exampplestreet 1;103#12121;104#Chicago;....
100#John;101#Wiliams;102#Exampplestreet 2;103#12345;104#Dallas;....
100#Mandy;101#Peterson;102#Exampplestreet 3;103#44554;104#LA;....
```

Is there any chance to handle the format of the provider? I never worked with a csv file formatted like this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though you will need to extract the field type from each value, not sure if this is relevant, but I have converted this into the key for the field in case you need it (it's not a huge amount of difference anyway).

Basically read each line as a CSV line (delimited by `;`), then for each field `explode()` it by `#` and if there are 2 fields then add it to the output array (`$data`)...

```
$fileName = "data.csv";
$handle = fopen ( $fileName, "r" );

while ( !feof($handle) )    {
    $fileData = fgetcsv( $handle, null, ";" );
    $data = [];
    foreach ( $fileData as $value ) {
        $values = explode("#", $value, 2);
        if ( count($values) == 2 )  {
            $data[ $values[0] ] = $values[1];
        }
    }

    print_r($data);
}
fclose($handle);
```

Output will be something like...

```
Array
(
    [100] => Alfred
    [101] => Mueller
    [102] => Exampplestreet 1
    [103] => 12121
    [104] => Chicago
)
```

If you don't need the field type and it is always three characters followed by a `#`, you can make this shorter by updating the value of the read array, using `substr()` to always remove the first 4 characters..

```
while ( !feof($handle) )    {
    $data = fgetcsv( $handle, null, ";" );
    foreach ( $data as &$value ) {
        $value = substr($value, 4);
    }

    print_r($data);
}
```

This will obviously be slower than loading it directly (and you need to add the database calls to the above).

Comment: Thanks Nigel, I will test it that way. Question is how long will it take to run through 200.000 lines. :(

Comment: No idea how long it will take, it depends on your database, your hardware.  You should use prepared statements for your SQL as well.